# I am searching for a loop query over multiple databases and insert result into existing table in one database to collect al data

Tags: sql-server

I am searching for a loop query over multiple databases and insert result into existing table in one database to collect al data.
There are 28 existing databases at the moment but when i start the query below it says table already exists at the second database.

when this works i want to loop a much larger query then this.

I also tried executing and union all but if a new database is added it must be collected autmatically.

See example i've tried below:

```
--drop table if exists [hulptabellen].dbo.HIdatabases
```

declare @dbList table (dbName varchar(128), indx int)

insert into @dbList
select dbName = dbname, row_number() over (order by dbname)
from [hulptabellen].dbo.HIdatabases

--declare variables for use in the while loop
declare @index int = 1
declare @totalDBs int = (select count(*) from @dbList)
declare @currentDB varchar(128)
declare @cmd varchar(300)
--define the command which will be used on each database.
declare @cmdTemplate varchar(300) =

'
use {dbName};

```
select * insert into [hulptabellen].dbo.cladrloc from {dbname}.dbo.cladrloc
```

'

--loop through each database and execute the command
while @index <= @totalDBs
begin
set @currentDB = (select dbName from @dbList where indx = @index)
set @cmd = replace(@cmdTemplate, '{dbName}', @currentDB)

```
execute(@cmd)

set @index += 1
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Create the table outside your loop and insert into the table this way:

```
INSERT INTO [hulptabellen].dbo.cladrloc  (col1,col2)
SELECT col1,col2
FROM {dbname}.dbo.cladrloc
```

FYI: When you use the following syntax, a new table is created, so it can be executed only once.

```
SELECT *
INTO [hulptabellen].dbo.cladrloc 
FROM {dbname}.dbo.cladrloc
```

Comment: Thanks Wouter, but the table needs to be reset every time. This query runs. The first database goes well. But when the second database is queried it stops. The actual statement is select * insert into [hulptabellen].dbo.cladrloc from {dbname}.dbo.cladrloc and the lookup for the loop must search for all existing database values in the table [hulptabellen].dbo.HIdatabases

Comment: Do you mean "reset" for every new database (in your loop)?  Then just truncate the table.

Comment: the results must be added to the table only at the first database is has to start with an empty table

Comment: Wouter, your tips worked. I drop the table at the start of the statement, then I create a new table before I loop over the databases. Thanks for your advice.